# .then() method ignored when using ES5 syntax

Tags: function, ecmascript-6, promise

Have this code working properly, with arrow functions:

```
f0(value)
    .then(val1          => f1(val1))
    .then(val2          => f2(val2))
    .catch(error        => result.textContent = error)
    .then(()            => final.textContent = "Done");
```

I am trying to version it using regular functions, as seen here:

```
f0(value)
    .then(function(val1){    f1(val1) })
    .then(function(val2){    f2(val2) })
    .catch(function(error){  result.textContent = error })
    .then(function(){        final.textContent = "Done" });
```

The code seems to ignore any rejected Promise, so if the first `.then()` is rejected, it continues to invoke the second one and so on.

This does not happen on the ES6 example above.

Am I making some syntax mistake?

Comment: It's because you're not returning anything under your `then` block. `.then(function(val1){   return f1(val1) })`

Comment: Thank you Ana, post your reply and Ill tick

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using the shorthand fat arrow function in your ES6 code version then you don't need to specify the `return` statement as it is implicitly implied under this scenario.

So when converting it to use a regular function, then you have to specify the `return` statement this time.

```js
f0(value)
    .then(function(val1){ return f1(val1) })
    .then(function(val2){ return f2(val2) })
    .catch(function(error){ return result.textContent = error })
    .then(function(){ return final.textContent = "Done" });
```

Answer (score 2):

You missing the `return` statement.
The equivalent of :

```
val1 => f1(val1)
```

is:

```
function(val1){  return  f1(val1) }
```

Comment: you are a magician, saved me a sh** ton of tries and errors

Answer (score -3):

I think you should have one then() and one catch() method for a signle promise. If you need several handlers, try to wrap them in a single function.

Comment: That is a thenable structure, you can chain several .then() methods and the first example works properly

Comment: I think you are missing the return statement in the second way

Comment: The entire point of `.then()` is that they can be chained. Otherwise you could just use callbacks.